# Check if object nested property exist and return its value

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to assign a variable with some object property and if that property doesn't exist than i'm assigning something else , for example:

Lets say our object is : `a = {"b":{"c":{"d":"e"}}};`

```
var SomeVar = (a && a.b && a.b.c && a.b.c.d) || OtherValue;
```

this approach is working as expected and if one of the nested properties doesn't exist i won't get an error like :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'c' of undefined
```

Is this the right approach? or there is a better way to do that?

Comment: Yep, that's how to do it without a helper function, though unfortunately it looks a bit ugly

Comment: if you happen to be using lodash, it's as easy as `_.get(a, 'b.c.d')`

Comment: @CertainPerformance But performance impact will be pretty much the same with this approach and the helper func approach right?

Comment: The performance impact is basically 0 no matter the method unless you happen to be doing this tens of thousands of times or more in an instant.

Comment: @CertainPerformance Great Thanks a Lot!!!!